# Google calendar integration with iOS app - subscription, billing charges

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, subscription, billing

I want to integrate Google calendar with my existing iOS app on App store. I will be using the Google iOS SDK and calendar APIs. I know I need to be a google developer and use developer console. My questions are,

1. What do I need to know regarding licensing etc?
2. What are the charges applicable in terms of subscription, API usage? Are these charges on yearly basis?
3. Where can I find info related to these?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the licensing, billing and others, then this [Cloud Platform Console Help](https://support.google.com/cloud#topic=) can help you with it. You will learn here all you need to do about Billing and Payments.